# T-SQL pulling data that lands in a specific month by inbound variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that I have that pulls all data that matches a current date, which is currently set to today.

I need to modify it so it pulls all records within a month, based on the numeric value of that month.

Old SQL:

```
WHERE CAST(RecordDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

I have an inbound variable called @RecordMonth. It is the numeric equivalent of the month (1 - 12). I need to pull all records that exist within that numeric month.

So, pseudocoded (with square brackets), the query becomes

```
WHERE CAST(RecordDate AS [MonthPartOfDate]) BETWEEN [FirstDayOf @RecordMonth] AND [LastDayOf @RecordMonth]
```

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method is:

```
WHERE YEAR(recorddate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
      MONTH(recorddate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

This prevents the use of indexes.  To use indexes, I would go for:

```
WHERE recorddate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      recorddate < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))
```

Comment: This makes sense. I guess my one admittedly beginner side question is, what does that look like using my @RecordMonth numeric inbound var?

Comment: replace  MONTH(GETDATE()) with @RecordMonth in the two places it appears

Answer (score 2):

You can declare two variables so, that it will treat as separate `startdate` & `enddate` :

```
declare @startdate date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(@RecordMonth), 1)
declare @endddate date = EOMONTH(@startdate)

select . . .
from table t
where (cast(recorddate as date) >= @startdate and 
       cast(recorddate as date) <= @enddate
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Late addition but useful. For many systems it is useful to have a dates kept in a memory optimised table. It can be joined to tables to provide easy, sargable date querying:

> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20000101', @NumberOfYears INT = 30;

-- prevent set or regional settings from interfering with 
-- interpretation of dates / literals

SET DATEFIRST 7;
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
SET LANGUAGE US_ENGLISH;

DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);

-- this is just a holding table for intermediate calculations:

CREATE TABLE [DateTable]
(
  [date]       DATE PRIMARY KEY, 
  [day]        AS DATEPART(DAY,      [date]),
  [month]      AS DATEPART(MONTH,    [date]),
  FirstOfMonth AS CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date]), 0)),
  [MonthName]  AS DATENAME(MONTH,    [date]),
  [week]       AS DATEPART(WEEK,     [date]),
  [ISOweek]    AS DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [date]),
  [DayOfWeek]  AS DATEPART(WEEKDAY,  [date]),
  [quarter]    AS DATEPART(QUARTER,  [date]),
  [year]       AS DATEPART(YEAR,     [date]),
  FirstOfYear  AS CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(YEAR,  DATEDIFF(YEAR,  0, [date]), 0)),
  Style112     AS CONVERT(CHAR(8),   [date], 112),
  Style101     AS CONVERT(CHAR(10),  [date], 101)
);

-- use the catalog views to generate as many rows as we need

INSERT [DateTable]([date]) 
SELECT d
FROM
(
  SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) AS y;

select * from [DateTable]
```

Comment: Aside: Don't forget to save the value of `@@DateFirst` so that you can interpret the `[week]` and `[DayOfWeek]` data correctly.